# Time complexity of my algorithm for creating a target array in the given order

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of this algorithm:

```
public int[] createTargetArray(int[] nums, int[] index) {
    int[] target = new int[nums.length];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < index.length) {
        for (k = target.length - 1; k > index[i]; k--)
            target[k] = target[k - 1];
        target[index[i]] = nums[i];
        i++;
    }
    return target;
}
```

I have provided the input/output and it's explanation below.

```
Input: nums = [0,1,2,3,4], index = [0,1,2,2,1]
Constraint: nums.length == index.length
Output: [0,4,1,3,2]
Explanation:
nums       index     target
0            0        [0]
1            1        [0,1]
2            2        [0,1,2]
3            2        [0,1,3,2]
4            1        [0,4,1,3,2]
```

According to my understanding, the `while` loop takes `O(n)` time and the inner `for` loop also takes `O(n)`. Is the time complexity of this solution `O(n^2)`? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** More accurately the complexity is `O(n * m)`, `O(n^2)` if we assume m = n;

> According to my understanding, the while loop takes O(n) time and the
> inner for loop also takes O(n). Is the time complexity of this
> solution O(n^2)?

First let us re-write your code to:

```
public int[] createTargetArray(int[] nums, int[] index) {
    int[] target = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
        for (int k = target.length - 1; k > index[i]; k--)
            target[k] = target[k - 1];
        target[index[i]] = nums[i];
    }
    return target;
}
```

The first loop iterates from `i = 0` until `index.length` and in the worst case scenario (*i.e.,* index[i] is zero) the second loop iteration from `k = target.length - 1` until `k = 1`. So begin `n` the number of elements in the array `index` and `m` the number of elements in the array `num`. The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n * m)`.

If one assume that `m = n` then one can say  `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the time complexity would be `O(n^2)`
The outer while loop is taking `n` steps that's clear and the inner for loop is dependant on the items of `index[]` array. Lets say that all the items are `0` in it then the inner loop will always run `n-1` steps so the time complexity would be n*(n-1) which is n*n since we are considering big O notation, thus `O(n^2)`